# input validation and quit loop, creating functions

Tags: c++, function, loops

I am trying to create a loop for input validation and another loop if the user wants to quit. also to create four functions one for the menu and one for each of the three area calculations.

Where should i implement the updated code? and should i use new variables or utilize the old ones. thank uou

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>    
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const float PI = 3.14159;
    int user_choice;
    // main screen prompting for choice
    cout << "\nGeometry Calculator\n"
        << "   1. Calculate the Area of a Circle\n"
        << "   2. Calculate the Area of a Rectangle\n"
        << "   3. Calculate the Area of a Triangle\n"
        << "   4. Quit\n"
        << "\nEnter you choice (1-4): ";
    cin >> user_choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (user_choice)
    {
        float area;
        // if user chooses 1
    case 1:
        int radius;
        // prompt user for radius
        cout << "What is the radius: ";
        cin >> radius;
        // if user enters radius as negative number
        if (radius < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nThe radius must be a positive number.\n"
                << "Try again.\n"
                << endl;
        }
        else
            // calculate area
        {
            area = PI * pow(radius, 2);

            cout << "The area of the circle is  "
                << area << endl;
        }
        break;
        // if user chooses 2
    case 2:
        float width, length;
        // prompt user for height and width
        cout << "What is the length? " << endl;
        cin >> length;

        if (length > 0)
        {
            cout << "What is the width? " << endl;
            cin >> width;
            // calculate and display area
            if (width > 0) {
                area = length * width;
                cout << "The area of rectangle is "
                    << area
                    << endl;
            }
            // if user enters a height or width less than 0
            else {
                cout << "\nWidth must be a positive number"
                    << endl;
                cout << "Try again." << endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nLength must be a positive number" << endl;
            cout << "Try again." << endl;
        }
        break;
        // if user chooses 3
    case 3:
        float height,
            base;
        // prompt user for base and height
        cout << "What is the base? ";
        cin >> base;

        if (base > 0)
        {
            cout << "What is the height? ";
            cin >> height;
            // calculate and display area
            if (height > 0)
            {
                area = (base * height) * .5;
                cout << "Area of triangle is "
                    << area
                    << endl;
            }
            // if user inputs a height or base less than 0
            else
            {
                cout << "\nHeight must be a positive number\n"
                    << "Try again."
                    << endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nBase length must be a positive number\n"
                << "Try again." << endl;
        }
        break;
        // if user chooses 4
    case 4:
        cout << "You have chose to quit the program. Good-bye." << endl;
        break;
        // if user enters input other than 1-4
    default:
        cout << "\nYour choice must be between 1 and 4.\n"
            << "Try again."
            << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: "*Where should i implement the updated code? and should i use new variables or utilize the old ones.*" it sounds like you're asking about software design. If you have a working program that you want some critiques on, you may ask over in [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is. The questions you have don't seem matter much one way or the other. I think your best approach would be to pick **one** of the functions and have a go (definitely don't try to do all of them at once). If you get stuck or it doesn't seem right then post the code you are struggling with. Then it will be a bit clearer what your concerns are, at the moment it's not very clear, to me at least.

Comment: Also it will probably be a bit easier to add the loops after you have written the functions. The code should be a bit more manageable then (assuming you did a good job with the functions).

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand what you want, you should create a `while(true)` loop that includes the user main choice (the main menu). I would do something like this:

```
void calculateCircleArea() {
    // Circle area calculation
}

void calculateRectangleArea() {
    // Rectangle area calculation
}

void calculateTriangleArea() {
    // Triangle area calculation
}

int main()
{
    // other main stuff

    int user_choice=0;
    while (user_choice!=4)
    {
        cout << "\nGeometry Calculator\n"
        << "   1. Calculate the Area of a Circle\n"
        << "   2. Calculate the Area of a Rectangle\n"
        << "   3. Calculate the Area of a Triangle\n"
        << "   4. Quit\n"
        << "\nEnter you choice (1-4): ";
        cin >> user_choice;

        if (user_choice<1 || user_choice>4)    // example to inform the user of a bad input
        {
            cout << "Wrong input\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INTMAX_MAX, '\n');
            // Ignoring and clearing all the input until the delimiter character ('\n')
            continue; // it is unnecessary, but this keyword will skip the cycle in which it is to its next iteration
        }
        
        switch(user_choice)
        {
            case 1:
            calculateCircleArea();
            break;
            case 2:
            calculateRectangleArea();
            break;
            case 3:
            calculateTriangleArea();
            break;
            case 4:
            // nothing, because the value of the variable user_choice is 4, so the loop will end
            break;
            default:
            // default stuff
            break;
        }    // switch
    }    // while

}    // main
```

As you can see, I've included three functions, one for each calculation. I suggest you to trying to use functions more, it will make your code more readable and clean, other that they are useful for other reason that you'll learn.

EDIT: as suggested, I didn't thought for an input of characters, so whenever an input is wrong, the input buffer will be cleared and it will ignore the last line inserted to prevent unintended behaviors.

Comment: This doesn't check the return value of `cin >> user_choice;` so if the user enters something that isn't a number it won't be extracted and you will end up in an infinite loop of "Wrong input"

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, that's intended, it will "force" the user to enter only a supported choices, the program will run until the proper signal to stop, so the value 4. The only way I could see an unintended behavior is when the user inserts a character with decimal value between 0 and 4, but it's highly improbable. Even so, it can be fixed easily using a `scanf(%d \n, &user_choice)` or an explicit cast: `user_choice = (int) user_choice`.
P.s. I recognize, though, it would be a good idea to add a length check on the input, but that, I think, does not concern what the op asked

Comment: Ok, but when I ran it and entered the letter "a" at the prompt it went into an infinite loop printing "Wrong Input" because the letter "a" is never removed from the input stream by the cin extraction to an integer variable.

Comment: You are completely right, I edited my answer to fix this case. I cleared the input in case of a wrong one. Thanks for pointing out.